# ValueError: time data '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' does not match format '2012-11-14 14:32:30'

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to convert the string `'2012-11-14 14:32:30'` to `datetime.datetime` object via `datetime.datetime.strptime` method using format string `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`.

Doing this, I get an error:

```
ValueError: time data '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' does not match format
 '2012-11-14 14:32:30'
```

Answer (score 37):

The correct syntax is:

```
datetime.strptime('2012-11-14 14:32:30', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

so first the string, then the format.

Read aloud:

```
ValueError: time data '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' does not match format '2012-11-14 14:32:30'
ValueError: time data '2012-11-14 14:32:30' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

Comment: great answer! :D